# Is there a standard type for () -> Void or () -> () in swift?

Tags: swift

few times I have to write a block with type

`() -> Void` or `() -> ()`

now if the block is nullable then becomes

`(() -> Void)?`

which is not very readable.

is there a standard type to use or the best I can do is to create a custom `typealias` ?

Comment: I've wondered the same thing. In my projects I always just created the `typealias`.

Comment: Even if there was a standard type, I prefer to create my own sensibly named type alias. (I like the readability it gives with Xcode auto completion) .

Answer (score 0):

There is no Swift standard type unfortunately for `(() -> Void)?` (or `(() -> ())?` which is arguably harder to read). If you check out the Swift Standard Library, you'll also see that `Void` is just a `typealias` for an empty tuple `()`:

```
typealias Void = ()
```

Which means you could write `(Void -> Void)?`, which is possibly slightly easier to read? Although in the standard library, this is as far as they've gone for a standard type in relation to this for readability.

Other than that, the only way to do this is with a custom `typealias`, for example:

```
typealias OptionalEmptyClosure = (() -> ())?
```